# Using std::begin(collection) vs collection.begin() in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Watching Stephan T. Lavavej: Core C++ #1, and noticed that he is using `begin(collection)` and not `collection.begin()`.

What are the advantages ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452130/when-to-use-stdbegin-and-stdend-instead-of-container-specific-versions  or  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570638/Ten-Cplusplus11-Features-Every-Cplusplus-Developer  may be relevant..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first advantage that springs to mind is that `std::begin(collection)` works with plain old arrays.