# Difference between vector::begin() and std::begin()

Tags: c++, vector

While iterating over a vector in c++, I noticed there is a `begin()` function in the standard library, and also a `begin()` as a member function of the `vector` class. What, if any, is the difference between the two, and which should be used over the other?

Example:

```
vector<int> numbers;
//Code to put values in my vector
for (vector<int>::iterator i = numbers.begin(); i < numbers.end(); i++)
    cout << *i << '\n';
```

vs:

```
vector<int> numbers;
//Code to put values in my vector
for (vector<int>::iterator i = std::begin(numbers); i < std::end(numbers); i++)
    cout << *i << '\n';
```

Comment: for containers they are the same. But `std::begin` also works for built-in arrays, which is very useful in template functions.

Comment: OT, but `++i` is probably more efficient than `i++` because the latter returns an iterator by value

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use std::begin and std::end instead of container specific versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452130/when-to-use-stdbegin-and-stdend-instead-of-container-specific-versions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use non-member begin and end functions in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593086/why-use-non-member-begin-and-end-functions-in-c11)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`std::begin()` was added in C++11 to make it easier to write generic code (e.g. in templates).  The most obvious reason for it is that plain C-style arrays do not have methods, hence no `.begin()`.  So you can use `std::begin()` with C-style arrays, as well as STL-style containers having their own `begin()` and `end()`.

If you're writing code which is not a template, you can ignore `std::begin()`; your fellow programmers would probably find it odd if you suddenly started using it everywhere just because it's new.

Comment: How about using it just because you want to be consistent?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I don't think this is exactly what @RalphWaldoEmerson had in mind when he said ""A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds," but I do think it would be distracting to see `std::begin()` used for no reason when we've done it the old way for decades.  It requires more typing for no benefit.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I know you are right, and yet, I just don't want to. :( It's the same for ++it for iterators and i++ for integers. Just the way I roll.

Comment: @JohnZwinck `begin(vec)` (thanks to ADL) is less typing than `vec.begin()` :)

Comment: Considering that if `std::begin` is available, then so are range-based for loops and `auto`; I'd prefer to not see the 2nd version at all!

Comment: @MattMcNabb: that's a great point, many uses of iterators are no longer needed at all in C++11.

Comment: @neilKirk `++itr` is better than `itr++`, because it doesn't need to remember the previous iterator to return. Tons of unnecessary memory usage, and memory is one of the slower things you can do millions of times. I'll admit that compilers might be able to optimize this one for you though. I also like to think of `++itr` as "add then use and `itr++` as use then add. The first one is conceptually simpler than the second, giving it another point. Regardless, I'd recommend using one or the other consistently. What are the benefits of changing back and forth based on the type?

Comment: is there any time or space complexity difference?

Answer (score 6):

The implementation of `std::begin()` for vectors simply calls `std::vector<T>::begin()`, so there is no difference between the two in this exact case.

Where `std::begin()` comes into its own is in generic algorithms:

```
template<typename Container>
void my_algorithm(Container c) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    auto const start = begin(c);  // ADL will find the appropriate overload
    auto const finish = end(c);
    // ... rest of code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler optimises your code, it doesn't matter which one you use. Otherwise, you might want to use the more OOP-looking format: numbers.begin()

This code has been plugged into Quick Bench for speed measurement:

```
std::vector<int> arr = {0,1,2};

static void formatA(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) { // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
    std::vector<int>::iterator itrA = arr.begin(); // arr.end();
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(itrA);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(formatA);

static void formatB(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) { // Code before the loop is not measured
    std::vector<int>::iterator itrB = begin(arr); // end(arr);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(itrB);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(formatB);
```

All compiled using STL=libstdc++ (GNU), results for `begin()` are as follows:

| params \ cpu_time (4dp) | formatA | formatB | Conclusion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [optim = none compiler = Clang 11.0 std = c++11](https://quick-bench.com/q/9XLg-rxpKtX0WVpq09LFx2WiN5w) | 2.1914 | 5.1870 | A is 2.4 times faster than B |
| [optim = none compiler = Clang 15.0 std = c++20](https://quick-bench.com/q/WVxfGV8_q5gPLfnTXlKg42TSyYA) | 2.0666 | 2.8974 | A is 1.4 times faster than B |
| [optim = O3 compiler = Clang 11.0 std = c++11](https://quick-bench.com/q/_BNgziOaDozl5Pal4zCMNE14j4U) | 1.1094 | 1.0130 | roughly equivalent runtime (equivalent assembly) |
| [optim = O3 compiler = Clang 15.0 std = c++20](https://quick-bench.com/q/CENUrtYjlMggRkY7l3B1T6O_tBA) | 1.0093 | 1.0007 | roughly equivalent runtime (equivalent assembly) |

Whereas for `end()`:

| params \ cpu_time (4dp) | formatA | formatB | Conclusion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [optim = none compiler = Clang 11.0 std = c++11](https://quick-bench.com/q/WAKlMrBorUPIWruoHiZ9obFf1Oc) | 2.5166 | 2.6341 | roughly equivalent runtime |
| [optim = none compiler = Clang 15.0 std = c++20](https://quick-bench.com/q/L46pntg_Xy2NZFKHv473pW7endM) | 2.3657 | 3.8461 | A is 1.6 times faster than B |
| [optim = O3 compiler = Clang 11.0 std = c++11](https://quick-bench.com/q/IpssAd2B4WfKYhNBnIVycT9YEsM) | 1.0045 | 1.0126 | roughly equivalent runtime (equivalent assembly) |
| [optim = O3 compiler = Clang 15.0 std = c++20](https://quick-bench.com/q/cOtHnbQ6tL2TqSL1QNEchdwcxU0) | 1.0047 | 1.0012 | roughly equivalent runtime (equivalent assembly) |

---

Without optimisation,
formatA `callq`s `<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::begin()>` and `end()` respectively, while
formatB `callq`s  `<decltype (({parm#1}.begin)()) std::begin<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)>` and `end()` respectively also. Time will be lost by deducing data type for formatB.

WITH optimisation, the compiler has already done the deducing, both will be using the following assembly and varies nothing else other than addresses:

```
mov    0x3c5b1(%rip),%rax        # 24f188 <arr>
mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
add    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rbx
```