# How can I fix this error: Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::vector<double>' and 'double')?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, operators

I want to obtain the average of some gyro readings and it involves dividing an `std::vector<double>` type with a double type, but I get the following error that reports

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::vector' and 'double')

How can I resolve this?

```
    double n_readings;
    std::vector<double> gyro_reading;
    for(int i = 0; i < n_readings; i++) {

        gyro_reading.push_back(gyro_z());
        msleep(1);

    }

    double average = gyro_reading/n_readings;
```

Comment: You can't divide a vector by a number. To get the average, sum up the elements of the vector, then divide by the size of the vector. Check this question to see ho to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221812/how-to-sum-up-elements-of-a-c-vector

Comment: `double average = std::accumulate(std::begin(gyro_reading),std::end(gyro_reading), 0.0) / n_readings`. Will require the `algorithm` header.

Comment: `std::valarray` supports member-wise operations directly, for `std::vector` you have to use loops or algorithms

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly valid question. @Mansoor You should post your comment as an answer, preferably with a short explanation as to why OPs attempt doesn't work.

Comment: @MaxVollmer: It lacks a compilable example, and is incomplete. E.g. what is the return type of `gyro_z()`?

Comment: I am an absolute fan of [MCVE]s, but come on. OPs error message is clear enough. And even if that's the reason, I see 4 downvotes but only one vote to close because it lacks a [MCVE]. How is OP supposed to improve their question that way.

Answer (score 5):

Your call to `gyro_reading/n_readings` requires a `/` operator to be defined between types `std::vector<T>` and `T`. Standard vector does not have such an operator. Even if it did, the result would probably be an elementwise divide rather than a sum reduction then divide.

The following:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
//...
double average = std::accumulate(std::begin(gyro_reading),std::end(gyro_reading), 0.0) / n_readings;
```

will accumulate all of the elements `gyro_reading`, the reduction is done using the `operator+` by default, then divide by `n_readings`. Also, you could use `gyro_reading.size()` instead of `n_readings` as this will always be consistent.

Comment: How does the sum part differ from ```std::accumulate(gyro_reading.begin(), gyro_reading.end(), 0.0)```? Would it lead to the same result?

Comment: If `gyro_reading` is a `std::vector`, then there is no distinction. The free functions are more generic and will work with C-arrays, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452130/when-to-use-stdbegin-and-stdend-instead-of-container-specific-versions).